# Azure The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared error DotNet Core

Tags: azure, .net-core

So I'm not seeing any issues when running this locally, but once deployed to Azure, checking the console is passing back :

*The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.*

I'm using DotNet core and razor pages my _Layout HTML page contains the below:

```
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</head>
```

Is there anything I need to do from an Azure stand point that anyone can think of?

Answer (score 0):

Found out more errors, was able to attach in Visual Studio which actually narrowed this down to connecting to the SQL instance on Azure.